# start games in android

Tags: android

i have PAC MAN game code 
how to call this game in android as a activity ..
and i want to call online game in android application than how to call online games in android application on a link , if user click on that particular game link , than game lunch form net online .. games like PAC MAN.
thanks

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Dimension d;
    Font smallfont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);

    FontMetrics fmsmall, fmlarge;
    Image ii;
    Color dotcolor = new Color(192, 192, 0);
    Color mazecolor;

    boolean ingame = false;
    boolean dying = false;

    final int blocksize = 24;
    final int nrofblocks = 15;
    final int scrsize = nrofblocks * blocksize;
    final int pacanimdelay = 2;
    final int pacmananimcount = 4;
    final int maxghosts = 12;
    final int pacmanspeed = 6;

    int pacanimcount = pacanimdelay;
    int pacanimdir = 1;
    int pacmananimpos = 0;
    int nrofghosts = 6;
    int pacsleft, score;
    int deathcounter;
    int[] dx, dy;
    int[] ghostx, ghosty, ghostdx, ghostdy, ghostspeed;

    Image ghost;
    Image pacman1, pacman2up, pacman2left, pacman2right, pacman2down;
    Image pacman3up, pacman3down, pacman3left, pacman3right;
    Image pacman4up, pacman4down, pacman4left, pacman4right;

    int pacmanx, pacmany, pacmandx, pacmandy;
    int reqdx, reqdy, viewdx, viewdy;

    final short leveldata[] =
    { 19, 26, 26, 26, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 22,
      21, 0,  0,  0,  17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20,
      21, 0,  0,  0,  17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 
      21, 0,  0,  0,  17, 16, 16, 24, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 
      17, 18, 18, 18, 16, 16, 20, 0,  17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20,
      17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0,  17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 24, 20, 
      25, 16, 16, 16, 24, 24, 28, 0,  25, 24, 24, 16, 20, 0,  21, 
      1,  17, 16, 20, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  17, 20, 0,  21,
      1,  17, 16, 16, 18, 18, 22, 0,  19, 18, 18, 16, 20, 0,  21,
      1,  17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0,  17, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0,  21, 
      1,  17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0,  17, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0,  21,
      1,  17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 18, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0,  21,
      1,  17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0,  21,
      1,  25, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 16, 16, 16, 18, 20,
      9,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  25, 24, 24, 24, 28 };

    final int validspeeds[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8 };
    final int maxspeed = 6;

    int currentspeed = 3;
    short[] screendata;
    Timer timer;


    public Board() {

        GetImages();

        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());

        screendata = new short[nrofblocks * nrofblocks];
        mazecolor = new Color(5, 100, 5);
        setFocusable(true);

        d = new Dimension(400, 400);

        setBackground(Color.black);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        ghostx = new int[maxghosts];
        ghostdx = new int[maxghosts];
        ghosty = new int[maxghosts];
        ghostdy = new int[maxghosts];
        ghostspeed = new int[maxghosts];
        dx = new int[4];
        dy = new int[4];
        timer = new Timer(40, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        GameInit();
    }


    public void DoAnim() {
        pacanimcount--;
        if (pacanimcount <= 0) {
            pacanimcount = pacanimdelay;
            pacmananimpos = pacmananimpos + pacanimdir;
            if (pacmananimpos == (pacmananimcount - 1) || pacmananimpos == 0)
                pacanimdir = -pacanimdir;
        }
    }


    public void PlayGame(Graphics2D g2d) {
        if (dying) {
            Death();
        } else {
            MovePacMan();
            DrawPacMan(g2d);
            moveGhosts(g2d);
            CheckMaze();
        }
    }


    public void ShowIntroScreen(Graphics2D g2d) {

        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 32, 48));
        g2d.fillRect(50, scrsize / 2 - 30, scrsize - 100, 50);
        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.drawRect(50, scrsize / 2 - 30, scrsize - 100, 50);

        String s = "Press s to start.";
        Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
        FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(small);

        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.setFont(small);
        g2d.drawString(s, (scrsize - metr.stringWidth(s)) / 2, scrsize / 2);
    }


    public void DrawScore(Graphics2D g) {
        int i;
        String s;

        g.setFont(smallfont);
        g.setColor(new Color(96, 128, 255));
        s = "Score: " + score;
        g.drawString(s, scrsize / 2 + 96, scrsize + 16);
        for (i = 0; i < pacsleft; i++) {
            g.drawImage(pacman3left, i * 28 + 8, scrsize + 1, this);
        }
    }


    public void CheckMaze() {
        short i = 0;
        boolean finished = true;

        while (i < nrofblocks * nrofblocks && finished) {
            if ((screendata[i] & 48) != 0)
                finished = false;
            i++;
        }

        if (finished) {
            score += 50;

            if (nrofghosts < maxghosts)
                nrofghosts++;
            if (currentspeed < maxspeed)
                currentspeed++;
            LevelInit();
        }
    }

    public void Death() {

        pacsleft--;
        if (pacsleft == 0)
            ingame = false;
        LevelContinue();
    }


    public void moveGhosts(Graphics2D g2d) {
        short i;
        int pos;
        int count;

        for (i = 0; i < nrofghosts; i++) {
            if (ghostx[i] % blocksize == 0 && ghosty[i] % blocksize == 0) {
                pos =
 ghostx[i] / blocksize + nrofblocks * (int)(ghosty[i] / blocksize);

                count = 0;
                if ((screendata[pos] & 1) == 0 && ghostdx[i] != 1) {
                    dx[count] = -1;
                    dy[count] = 0;
                    count++;
                }
                if ((screendata[pos] & 2) == 0 && ghostdy[i] != 1) {
                    dx[count] = 0;
                    dy[count] = -1;
                    count++;
                }
                if ((screendata[pos] & 4) == 0 && ghostdx[i] != -1) {
                    dx[count] = 1;
                    dy[count] = 0;
                    count++;
                }
                if ((screendata[pos] & 8) == 0 && ghostdy[i] != -1) {
                    dx[count] = 0;
                    dy[count] = 1;
                    count++;
                }

                if (count == 0) {
                    if ((screendata[pos] & 15) == 15) {
                        ghostdx[i] = 0;
                        ghostdy[i] = 0;
                    } else {
                        ghostdx[i] = -ghostdx[i];
                        ghostdy[i] = -ghostdy[i];
                    }
                } else {
                    count = (int)(Math.random() * count);
                    if (count > 3)
                        count = 3;
                    ghostdx[i] = dx[count];
                    ghostdy[i] = dy[count];
                }

            }
            ghostx[i] = ghostx[i] + (ghostdx[i] * ghostspeed[i]);
            ghosty[i] = ghosty[i] + (ghostdy[i] * ghostspeed[i]);
            DrawGhost(g2d, ghostx[i] + 1, ghosty[i] + 1);

            if (pacmanx > (ghostx[i] - 12) && pacmanx < (ghostx[i] + 12) &&
                pacmany > (ghosty[i] - 12) && pacmany < (ghosty[i] + 12) &&
                ingame) {

                dying = true;
                deathcounter = 64;

            }
        }
    }


    public void DrawGhost(Graphics2D g2d, int x, int y) {
        g2d.drawImage(ghost, x, y, this);
    }


    public void MovePacMan() {
        int pos;
        short ch;

        if (reqdx == -pacmandx && reqdy == -pacmandy) {
            pacmandx = reqdx;
            pacmandy = reqdy;
            viewdx = pacmandx;
            viewdy = pacmandy;
        }
        if (pacmanx % blocksize == 0 && pacmany % blocksize == 0) {
            pos =
 pacmanx / blocksize + nrofblocks * (int)(pacmany / blocksize);
            ch = screendata[pos];

            if ((ch & 16) != 0) {
                screendata[pos] = (short)(ch & 15);
                score++;
            }

            if (reqdx != 0 || reqdy != 0) {
                if (!((reqdx == -1 && reqdy == 0 && (ch & 1) != 0) ||
                      (reqdx == 1 && reqdy == 0 && (ch & 4) != 0) ||
                      (reqdx == 0 && reqdy == -1 && (ch & 2) != 0) ||
                      (reqdx == 0 && reqdy == 1 && (ch & 8) != 0))) {
                    pacmandx = reqdx;
                    pacmandy = reqdy;
                    viewdx = pacmandx;
                    viewdy = pacmandy;
                }
            }

            // Check for standstill
            if ((pacmandx == -1 && pacmandy == 0 && (ch & 1) != 0) ||
                (pacmandx == 1 && pacmandy == 0 && (ch & 4) != 0) ||
                (pacmandx == 0 && pacmandy == -1 && (ch & 2) != 0) ||
                (pacmandx == 0 && pacmandy == 1 && (ch & 8) != 0)) {
                pacmandx = 0;
                pacmandy = 0;
            }
        }
        pacmanx = pacmanx + pacmanspeed * pacmandx;
        pacmany = pacmany + pacmanspeed * pacmandy;
    }


    public void DrawPacMan(Graphics2D g2d) {
        if (viewdx == -1)
            DrawPacManLeft(g2d);
        else if (viewdx == 1)
            DrawPacManRight(g2d);
        else if (viewdy == -1)
            DrawPacManUp(g2d);
        else
            DrawPacManDown(g2d);
    }

    public void DrawPacManUp(Graphics2D g2d) {
        switch (pacmananimpos) {
        case 1:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman2up, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        case 2:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman3up, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        case 3:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman4up, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        default:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        }
    }


    public void DrawPacManDown(Graphics2D g2d) {
        switch (pacmananimpos) {
        case 1:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman2down, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        case 2:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman3down, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        case 3:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman4down, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        default:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        }
    }


    public void DrawPacManLeft(Graphics2D g2d) {
        switch (pacmananimpos) {
        case 1:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman2left, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        case 2:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman3left, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        case 3:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman4left, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        default:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        }
    }


    public void DrawPacManRight(Graphics2D g2d) {
        switch (pacmananimpos) {
        case 1:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman2right, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        case 2:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman3right, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        case 3:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman4right, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        default:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
            break;
        }
    }


    public void DrawMaze(Graphics2D g2d) {
        short i = 0;
        int x, y;

        for (y = 0; y < scrsize; y += blocksize) {
            for (x = 0; x < scrsize; x += blocksize) {
                g2d.setColor(mazecolor);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

                if ((screendata[i] & 1) != 0) // draws left
                {
                    g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y + blocksize - 1);
                }
                if ((screendata[i] & 2) != 0) // draws top
                {
                    g2d.drawLine(x, y, x + blocksize - 1, y);
                }
                if ((screendata[i] & 4) != 0) // draws right
                {
                    g2d.drawLine(x + blocksize - 1, y, x + blocksize - 1,
                                 y + blocksize - 1);
                }
                if ((screendata[i] & 8) != 0) // draws bottom
                {
                    g2d.drawLine(x, y + blocksize - 1, x + blocksize - 1,
                                 y + blocksize - 1);
                }
                if ((screendata[i] & 16) != 0) // draws point
                {
                    g2d.setColor(dotcolor);
                    g2d.fillRect(x + 11, y + 11, 2, 2);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void GameInit() {
        pacsleft = 3;
        score = 0;
        LevelInit();
        nrofghosts = 6;
        currentspeed = 3;
    }


    public void LevelInit() {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < nrofblocks * nrofblocks; i++)
            screendata[i] = leveldata[i];

        LevelContinue();
    }


    public void LevelContinue() {
        short i;
        int dx = 1;
        int random;

        for (i = 0; i < nrofghosts; i++) {
            ghosty[i] = 4 * blocksize;
            ghostx[i] = 4 * blocksize;
            ghostdy[i] = 0;
            ghostdx[i] = dx;
            dx = -dx;
            random = (int)(Math.random() * (currentspeed + 1));
            if (random > currentspeed)
                random = currentspeed;
            ghostspeed[i] = validspeeds[random];
        }

        pacmanx = 7 * blocksize;
        pacmany = 11 * blocksize;
        pacmandx = 0;
        pacmandy = 0;
        reqdx = 0;
        reqdy = 0;
        viewdx = -1;
        viewdy = 0;
        dying = false;
    }

    public void GetImages()
    {

      ghost = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/ghost.png")).getImage();
      pacman1 = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/pacman.png")).getImage();
      pacman2up = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/up1.png")).getImage();
      pacman3up = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/up2.png")).getImage();
      pacman4up = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/up3.png")).getImage();
      pacman2down = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/down1.png")).getImage();
      pacman3down = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/down2.png")).getImage(); 
      pacman4down = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/down3.png")).getImage();
      pacman2left = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/left1.png")).getImage();
      pacman3left = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/left2.png")).getImage();
      pacman4left = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/left3.png")).getImage();
      pacman2right = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/right1.png")).getImage();
      pacman3right = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/right2.png")).getImage();
      pacman4right = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../pacpix/right3.png")).getImage();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
      super.paint(g);

      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

      g2d.setColor(Color.black);
      g2d.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);

      DrawMaze(g2d);
      DrawScore(g2d);
      DoAnim();
      if (ingame)
        PlayGame(g2d);
      else
        ShowIntroScreen(g2d);

      g.drawImage(ii, 5, 5, this);
      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
      g.dispose();
    }

    class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

          int key = e.getKeyCode();

          if (ingame)
          {
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            {
              reqdx=-1;
              reqdy=0;
            }
            else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            {
              reqdx=1;
              reqdy=0;
            }
            else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            {
              reqdx=0;
              reqdy=-1;
            }
            else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            {
              reqdx=0;
              reqdy=1;
            }
            else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE && timer.isRunning())
            {
              ingame=false;
            }
            else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_PAUSE) {
                if (timer.isRunning())
                    timer.stop();
                else timer.start();
            }
          }
          else
          {
            if (key == 's' || key == 'S')
          {
              ingame=true;
              GameInit();
            }
          }
      }

          public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
              int key = e.getKeyCode();

              if (key == Event.LEFT || key == Event.RIGHT || 
                 key == Event.UP ||  key == Event.DOWN)
              {
                reqdx=0;
                reqdy=0;
              }
          }
      }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply "call the game code". You can study, understand and reuse the logic and build a new game in Android. Even the reuse of this code will require a lot of refactoring.

If you want to build android games, then you can use a framework like Cocos2D.

Here's a good tutorial:

http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/

Comment: their is no way to call any online games like flash games our other java code games? ...
their is only way to make games in Cocos2D and than play in android application ?

Comment: you can run flash games in browser if the browser supports it. You will have to re-code games in other platforms to android platform (unless you are using some kind of emulator. Performance might take a hit here). Cocos2D is just one framework and there are others as well.

Comment: thanks ...
 tell me one thing  . if game is already installed on phone . 
how to call that game in my application or i click on a link than launch that game

Comment: If you know it's package or main activity name, you can call it in your app. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application

Comment: thanks for helping 
i find it , how to call other applications ..

final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);